# Send pointers over network instead of full class with data

Tags: java, networking, arraylist

I'm working on implementing multiplayer to a RTS game that I'm working on. I have a class GameObject that every item (buildings, units, trees etc.) extends. This GameObject class holds all info about an item (name, health, position, texture and so on). An `ArrayList<GameObject> gameObjects` stores all items.

Then I have an `ArrayList<GameObject> selector` that contains items that the user currently has selected. Let's say the user clicks on a tank, then this tank would be stored in `selector`. If he then right click somewhere he is telling the tank to go to the mouse's coordinates. And I also need to tell all other players this by sending the selector ArrayList and the mouse coordinates to the server so that the server can pass it on to the other clients.

Now to the problem. Sending the selector means sending a lot of unnecessary data (for instance textures) since the class GameObject holds this info. And I would also have to implement serializable to every class GameObject uses. So my question is if I somehow can have an ArrayList that only stores some sort of pointers to the actual gameObjects ArrayList. So that when the user selects the tank, I store a pointer to the tank in the ArrayList gameObjects.

I realize it might be a bit confusing. Hope you understand.

Comment: Why don't you build an array list of unique ids referencing gameobjects and send that instead?

Comment: @cyberz So that when I add an item to the game I basically give it an unique number and then store this number in my selector array?

Comment: yes, so you don't send the objects themself over the network but simply their unique reference

Comment: You are by no means obliged to use Java Serialization, BTW.

Comment: You could mark all of the fields you don't want to send over using the transient keyword, so that they would not be serialized. Of course you'd have to be careful on using these objects once they're deserialized on the other end, so that you won't get any NullPointerEx thrown around.